# Path generation algorithm confusion

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I asked for some help in creating a path generation algorithm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819566/random-path-generation-algorithm), where Taekahn was gracious enough to help me. I understand all of his code except for one section, the `IsNotMarked` function.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j6gkzbr5/28/)

```
function IsNotMarked(row, column) {
    //if row is out of bounds, it is not marked
    if (row < 0 || row >= matrix.length) return true;

    //if column is out of bounds, it is not marked
    if (column < 0 || column >= matrix[row].length) return true;

    //if ahead node (east of East Node) is not part of path... it's not marked
    return matrix[row][column].data('partOfPath') != true;
}
```

Namely: `return matrix[row][column].data('partOfPath') != true;`

The function above `IsNotMarked()`, `CreateNewFrontier()`, is supposed to check the neighboring nodes in each direction (north, east, south, west) to first check if they are in bounds...

Then `AddToFrontier()` is supposed to check the nodes neighboring *those* nodes (node east of the East Node) to check if they are not marked (part of path), because to maintain the single path, a node can only have one neighbor.

**Questions:**

1) I tried replacing

```
return matrix[row][column].data('partOfPath') != true;
```

with

```
if (matrix[row][column].data('partOfPath') == false) return true;
```

which I think means the same thing, but then it only marks the root node and doesn't work. How are those two different? Isn't it true, that if that node isn't part of path, then return `IsNotMarked` as true?

2) I also tried simplifying it by removing `IsNotMarked()` altogether by simply checking if the node is part of the path directly in `AddToFrontier()`, but now nothing draws at all:

```
    if (row - 1 >= 0 && matrix[row-1][column].data('partOfPath') == true) { //check if it IS marked... 
        markedNeighbors++;
    }
```

Any help would be awesome!

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference happens when `matrix[row][column].data('partOfPath')` is neither true nor false (e.g. `null` or `undefined`).

In this case, the following statement returns `true`:

```
return matrix[row][column].data('partOfPath') != true;
```

But the following returns false (note how you also need the else statement):

```
if (matrix[row][column].data('partOfPath') == false)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Comment: `return matrix[row][column].data('partOfPath') != true;` - I thought this returns false... since `!= true` = false, right?

Comment: if `matrix[row][column].data('partOfPath')` is undefined, it will return true because `(undefined != true)` is true.

Comment: Is there any difference between jQuery's `.data` method and storing a property as part of a class? My issue is, I'm no longer creating this maze using DOM elements, but rather adding instances of a tile class to my game's Tiled tilemap. In my `tiled` entity, I have `this.partOfPath = false;`, versus in the DOM (working) version, I have `matrix[row][column].data('partOfPath', true);`... I've added an image above, My game's tiles keep going in the same pattern... Even though my code is exactly the same as the one where I use the DOM elements

Comment: From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/), it looks like `.data()` is only designed to work with DOM elements. Can you use something like `matrix[row][column].partOfPath != false` instead?

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I think you may have misread. Now that I'm doing `.partOfPath` as a property of the class object, it is causing problems

Comment: I see. There shouldn't be any difference... my guess is that something else is going on that you haven't mentioned here.